# Get list Of Files in a Directory in Foxpro

Tags: file, directory, foxpro

How can i get list of files in a directory programatically in foxpro?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ADIR()   -- create an array based on a directory using whatever wildcard...

```
local array MyFiles[1,5]
nFilesFound = ADIR( MyFiles, "C:\Somepath\*.dbf" )

for i = 1 to nFilesFound
   ? "Name Of File: ", MyFiles[ i, 1]
   ? "Size: ", MyFiles[ i, 2]
   */ i,3 = date... i,4 = time,  i,5 = attributes
endfor
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the File System Object to get more information:

```
fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
fld=fso.getfolder(lcFolderName)
for each fil in fld.files
   ?"Name Of File: ", fil.name
   ?"Size: ", fil.size
   ?"Date created:", fil.DateCreated
   ?"Last modified:", fil.DateLastModified
next
```

Comment: Excellent example and I wish I could find the rest of these type of objects...  Thank you geoff franklin.