# Returning Filename with wildcards in VFP 9

Tags: string, filepath, visual-foxpro

I am trying to locate the full name of a file using a wildcard. The code I have is:

```
MLCNo=crjbis.ffromlot
subfolder=LEFT(mlcno,3)
filename=SYS(2000,'S:\MLC\MLC#\'+subfolder+'xx\'+mlcno+'21391*.pdf')
pathname="S:\MLC\MLC#\"+subfolder+"xx\"+filename
```

Pathname is passed to a print function to print the file. All of this works great if I don't use a variable in the SYS function (even with a wildcard). I should add that there will only ever be one file returned by the wildcard. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!!!
Tammy

Comment: Are you trying to search a subdirectory tree for the file that matches your specification?

Comment: Yes. I did find another way, using ADIR(). this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483215/get-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-foxpro. Thanks!