# How to loop through nested directories in Foxpro given the initial start directory

Tags: loops, directory, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to loop through a local directory and print out the name of all subdirectories and files within. The start path of the search is provided, and it can be possible that there are nested directories.

The start directory looks like:

[image]

and for example, within the appendix directory, we have:

[image]

And the directory nesting could go on as many times, but for this example these two sub directories a1 and a2 only contain some .txt files.

I have seen some other similar question like [Get list Of Files in a Directory in Foxpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483215/get-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-foxpro) but I do not seem to get anything correct with what is shown here. If this question and answer does indeed apply directly to my question maybe someone can help clarify how I can utilize this answer.

Right now I just want to print out the names of all content (directories and files) as the loop goes through each subdirectory until it has gone through all items inside the initial starting directory. It would also be nice to print out other information like the last modified date of each item as well.
The output with just the file names would look something like:

**appendix**

**a1**

**a1text.txt**

**a2**

**a2text.txt**

**aTotal.txt**

**index** (nothing inside index so moving on)

**names**

**allnames.txt**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the following sample code, it evaluates all File items in the parametrized start folder, and when it finds a sub-Folder, there it starts itself recursively to do the same again.

As for your comments asking for additional explanations:
The local <kbd>F1</kbd> Help file that ships with `visual-foxpro`, i.e. its community version content, is also available online:

[vfphelp-adir](https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12ppae.htm)

> The ADir() function places information about files into an array and then returns the number of files.
> 1: File names
> 2: File sizes
> 3: Dates last modified
> 4: Times last modified
> 5: File attributes

[vfphelp-directory](https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pqbm.htm)

> The Directory() function checks whether a string is an existing File System folder name

[vfphelp-addbs](https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pp9h.htm)

> The AddBS() function adds a trailing backslash to a string if there is none yet

Don't hesitate to comment on additional aspects.

```
* creating a temp. table to store and show the results
CREATE CURSOR filesandfolders (cpath C(254), cfile C(254))
INDEX on LEFT(cpath,120) + LEFT(cfile,120) TAG myorder

GetFilesRecursively(HOME())
*!* GetFilesRecursively(HOME(),.T.)

GO TOP IN filesandfolders
BROWSE WIDTH 60
RETURN

PROCEDURE GetFilesRecursively(tcFolder, tlNoSubfolders)
    ASSERT ( VARTYPE(m.tcFolder) = 'C' )
    ASSERT ( VARTYPE(m.tlNoSubfolders) = 'L' )

    LOCAL lnFile, laFiles[1], lcFileOrFolder
    FOR lnFile = 1 TO ADIR(laFiles, ADDBS(m.tcFolder)+'*', 'D')
        lcFileOrFolder = LOWER(laFiles[m.lnFile, 1])
        IF EMPTY( STRTRAN(m.lcFileOrFolder,'.') )
            LOOP
        ENDIF

        IF DIRECTORY( ADDBS(m.tcFolder)+m.lcFileOrFolder, 1 )
            IF !m.tlNoSubfolders
                GetFilesRecursively(ADDBS(m.tcFolder)+m.lcFileOrFolder)
            ENDIF
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO filesandfolders VALUES ( ;
                m.tcFolder, m.lcFileOrFolder )
        ENDIF
    ENDFOR
ENDPROC
```

[image: Result image]

*Edited*: As for the OP's comment:

> lcFileOrFolder values are . or .. Why does adir() create values like this?

The dots get into the first ADir() result elements when its 3rd parameter is "D"(irectory). IDE Command Window example:

```
CD HOME()
? ADIR(laDir, "*")
? laDir[1,1] && no "D" no dots, first element is a file name, e.g."Beautify.APP"
? ADIR(laDir, "*", "D")
? laDir[1,1] && dot "."
? laDir[2,1] && double dot ".."
```

That behavior is not documented AFAIK, might perhaps have been an ancient feature related to the DOS/FoxPro `CD` command

Comment: Thanks @stefan-wubbe. I will check this out more tomorrow. Does ADIR() provide properties of subdirectories and files like date last modified? If so, how would you could we retrieve that in this same code outline. Thanks.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to explain what some of the pieces of this code are doing, either with embedded comments, or with a description here? I think I understand most, but what is the last if/else statement checking?

Comment: Someone removed my previous comment - _"Does ADIR() provide properties[?]"_ Yes, see the updated answer, i.e. here: [vfphelp-adir](https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12ppae.htm)

Comment: @DizzleBeans, what ADIR() returns might be a folder or a file. Last if .. else ... endif block is checking if that is a folder, if it is getting its subfolders and files, else inserting it as a file.

Comment: How does the tlNoSubfolders variable get set? If we call the procedure as: GetFilesRecursively(HOME()) without the second parameter, I dont exactly see how the program executes the final if/else statement by checking the NoSubfolders variable? Thanks.

Comment: Also could you explain why the first If empty () statement is needed? After printing out the variables each iteration, I do not see why some of the lcFileOrFolder values are . or .. Why does adir() create values like this?

Comment: _"How does the tlNoSubfolders variable get set?"_ 
That Q is quite broad, A does not really fit into a comment --`tlNoSubfolders` is a parameter in the function's signature: `GetFilesRecursively(tcFolder, tlNoSubfolders)` --  Vfp is a weak typing language, parameters can be omitted. If a parameter does not get sent, it's being received as the default value which is a boolean False, i.e. `.F.` in Vfp.

Comment: _"lcFileOrFolder values are . or .. Why does adir() create values like this?"_ 
That Q is also too broad for a comment-answer, see the bottom addition of the edited answer itself

Comment: Thanks @StefanWuebbe for the explanations. My last question might need a new post, but I am using this code outline to write an XML file which will have nested node folders and files depending on how many subdirectories exist within a directory and so on. I think the code you've provided should allow for this, but right now I am running into a problem where all the directory nodes get created under the root node, where what I am looking for is that subdirectories will get put under the node of the directory and not always the root directory. Let me know what you think. I can make new post too.

Comment: _"XML file which will have nested node folders and files depending on how many subdirectories exist within a directory and so on. I think the code you've provided should allow for this"_ I think so too. If your current attempt does not do what you want, I'd also think a separate question with minimized-repro scenario could be your best option